# Extracting tables from .pdf

Tags: import, code-request, pdf-format

Can we construct some automated method for extracting tables from pdfs?

I can get decently far by just copy and pasting its content and splitting at newlines but it would be great if it was possible to detect tables automatically and extract its data and re-structure it as an appropriate Mathematica expression.

Is there any code for this?